# Is this behavior classifiable as a bifurcation?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

This question arose from a Dynamical Systems lecture I just came from. The professor constructed a system $\dot{r} = 1-r$, $\dot{\theta} = 1-r$, and showed that as $r(t)$ converges to $1$, $\theta(t)$ also converges to some finite $\theta_*$ (in particular, to $\theta_* = 1-r(0)+\theta(0)$). The phase portrait in $(x, y)$ is below.

[image]

However, for $\dot{r} = (1-r)^3$, $\dot{\theta} = 1-r$, in which $r(t)$ converges much more slowly to $1$, we have that $\theta(t)$ does not converge. Again, the phase portrait in $(x, y)$ is below.

[image]

It occurred to me that if we take the system $\dot{r} = \mathrm{sgn}(1-r)\lvert 1-r\rvert^m$, $\dot{\theta} = 1-r$, there is some $m = \inf\{m : \theta(t)\text{ does not converge}\} \in [1, 3]$. With a little work, we can see that this is $m = 2$ (in particular, just use separation of variables to solve $\dot{r} = -(r-1)^m$ for $r > 1$ and plug into $\dot{\theta}$, which we then see is not integrable for $m \geq 2$).

I worked this out for the professor and asked whether this event was classifiable as a bifurcation. He didn't seem to think so, but he also hadn't considered the problem in any depth. It seems to me that the limit cycle is stable for all $m \geq 1$, but the individual points of the limit cycle lose asymptotic stability. This doesn't seem to match the description of any type of bifurcation listed [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bifurcation#Classification_of_bifurcations). Does anybody have an idea of how to classify the behavior of this system around $m = 2$?

Comment: Just a comment passing by. The reason that you can't find this situation in the list of common bifurcations is because yours is a bit uncommon. It's not very typical situation when you have a whole manifold of equilibrium points even at single point in parameter space (and you have this for all values of $m > 0$).

Comment: Do you have any intuition as to how this phenomenon may be more rigorously described? Is this indeed a bifurcation (i.e. does there not exist a homeomorphism that takes the phase plane for $m = 2+\epsilon$ to the one for $m = 2-\epsilon$ for all small $\epsilon > 0$?)

Comment: It looks a bit like a blue sky catastrophe, but just as @Evgeny mentioned, the situation with the circle of fixed points is rather singular. I would be tempted to use geometric blow-up on the circle, which would hopefully clarify the situation and would give $m=2$ as the limiting case. A very interesting problem, though!

Comment: To add here: in this system there is a $O(2)$-symmetry: you rotate a solution, you get another solution. I'm not really sure, but if we somehow factorize this symmetry (it could be done, but I always forget the way it can be done), then obtained 1D system would have something that is called "relative equilibrium". Maybe you can relate your bifurcation with bifurcation of this relative equilibrium if something happens with it. But I can't tell you how particularly to do symmetry reduction here.